# MySQL - left join or nested select for filtering non-existing rows?

Tags: mysql, select, join

Table structure for `catalog_product_category_bindings`:

```
`productID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
`categoryID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Table structure for `catalog_products`:

```
`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
misc unrelated columns
```

Task: get data of all products which are not bound to any category (no entry in `catalog_product_category_bindings`).

Query #1 (using LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT cp.* FROM catalog_products AS cp
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_category_bindings AS cpcb
ON cp.id = cpcb.productID
WHERE cpcb.categoryID IS NULL
```

Query #2 (using nested select):

```
SELECT cp.* FROM catalog_products AS cp
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT productID FROM catalog_product_category_bindings)
```

Both queries seem to be quite similar in terms of speed on my tables (I don't have much in there), but I believe the second one is worse in performance since it probably loops over every `id` in the `catalog_products` table and compares it to every `productID` from `catalog_product_category_bindings`. Not to mention it might not return anything and break the query altogether (though that would only happen if the table were to be truncated).

Which would you say is better? I, personally, prefer #1 since it fits better into my query builder and seems generally better.

Comment: You are right. I too support you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your columns are defined as `NOT NULL` MySQL optimizes the `NOT IN()` query anyway to a not exists. There's not much difference between the two.

[Here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)'s a must read about the topic.

Comment: Alright, I'll stick to my LEFT JOIN since they're the same performance. Thanks for the link!